# To compute improper integral $\int_3^{5}\frac{x^{2}\, dx}{\sqrt{x-3}{\sqrt{5-x}}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals, self-learning

I am given improper integral as

$$\int_3^{5}\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{x-3}{\sqrt{5-x}}}dx$$

**DOUBT**

I see that problem is at both the end points, so i need to split up the integral. But problem seems to me that when i split up integral one of terms in denominator which is ${5-x}$ becomes negative. **So how do i split up the integral** ? Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: Could you fix the denominator of the integrand ? It is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i tried but square root doesnt appear over 5-x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest that you do $u=x-4$ to get an integral from $-1$ to $1$. It will be
$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{(u+4)^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du=\int_{-1}^1-\sqrt{1-u^2}+\frac{8u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}+\frac{17}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du.
$$
The first term in the integrand gives $-\pi/2$, since it represents (minus) the area of a half circle. The second term gives nothing, since it is odd, and the interval is even. The last term gives
$$
\bigl[17\arcsin u\bigr]_{-1}^1=17(\pi/2-(-\pi/2))=17\pi.
$$
All in all, the integral equals $-\pi/2+17\pi=33\pi/2$.

Comment: Few questions 1. How did you know about which substitution to use? 2.How did you simplified the integral? Thanks

Comment: Nice and simple !

Comment: @TaylorTed. Just for symmetry, I suppose : $\frac{3+5}2=4$

Comment: 1) The limits and the square roots hinted me (and as Claude mention, to have a symmetric interval). 2) Expanding the numerator gives $u^2+8u+16$, which can be written as $(u^2-1)+8u+17$.

Comment: @mickep expanding the numerator we obtain $-(x^2-8x+15)$ which we can write as $1-(x-4)^2$.

Comment: @Math-fun I don't follow. Do you mean what is inside the square roots from the beginning?

Comment: @mickep your solution is of course neat :-) I was trying to make clear why you made such a variable change choice in the beginning of your post.

Comment: @Math-fun Because I wanted to integrate over a symmetric interval. Of course one could use symmetry around $x=4$ instead (I think that is your point?). To me it is easier to use symmetry around $x=0$.

Comment: @mickep this is right, thanks :-)

Answer (score 8):

**Beta Function Approach**

Substituting $x\mapsto2x+3$,
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_3^5\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{(x-3)(5-x)}}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{(2x+3)^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{(3(1-x)+5x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\\
&=9\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
+30\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)x\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
+25\int_0^1\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\\
&=9\operatorname{B}\left(\frac52,\frac12\right)
+30\operatorname{B}\left(\frac32,\frac32\right)
+25\operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,\frac52\right)\\
&=9\cdot\frac38\pi
+30\cdot\frac18\pi
+25\cdot\frac38\pi\\
&=\frac{33}2\pi
\end{align}
$$
using the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

---

**Trigonometric Subsitution**

After the substitution $x\mapsto2x+3$, we can use $x\mapsto\sin^2(x)$
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_3^5\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{(x-3)(5-x)}}\\
&=9\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
+30\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)x\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
+25\int_0^1\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\\
&=9\int_0^{\pi/2}2\cos^4(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
+30\int_0^{\pi/2}2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
+25\int_0^{\pi/2}2\sin^4(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=9\cdot\frac38\pi
+30\cdot\frac18\pi
+25\cdot\frac38\pi\\
&=\frac{33}2\pi
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Not clear your second step.Which substitution you used? Could you add more details

Comment: @TaylorTed: sorry, I have added a bit more explanation.

Comment: It's nice to be familiar with the beta function. Then, an integral as this one can be pushed through without fear! :)

Comment: @mickep: indeed, but showing alternate approaches is something i always appreciate.

Comment: Great answer! Are there any other functions are useful for calculating integrals? (like Gamma and Beta).

Comment: @Rowan: I have found [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) to be the most useful after trig and exponential functions. After those, [Digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) functions are also useful.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$(5-x)(x-3)=(-x^2-15+8x)=(1-(x-4)^2)$$
now let $x=sint$ and you will get rid of the square root. And be careful about the range, which changes when you changing your variable.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, the following

$$x^2=A(x-3)(5-x)+B(8-2x)+C$$

On solving we get

$$x^2=-(x-3)(5-x)-4(8-2x)+17$$
Now, we have 
$$\int_{3}^{5}\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{(x-3)}\sqrt{(5-x)}}$$
$$=\int_{3}^{5}\frac{(-(x-3)(5-x)-4(8-2x)+17)dx}{\sqrt{(x-3)}\sqrt{(5-x)}}$$
$$=-\int_{3}^{5}\frac{(x-3)(5-x)dx}{\sqrt{(x-3)}\sqrt{(5-x)}}-4\int_{3}^{5}\frac{(8-2x)dx}{\sqrt{(x-3)}\sqrt{(5-x)}}+17\int_{3}^{5}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-3)}\sqrt{(5-x)}}$$
$$=-\int_{3}^{5}\sqrt{(x-3)}\sqrt{(5-x)}-4\int_{3}^{5}\frac{(8-2x)dx}{\sqrt{8x-x^2-15}}+17\int_{3}^{5}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(x-4)^2}}$$
$$=-\int_{3}^{5}\sqrt{1-(x-4)^2}-4\int_{3}^{5}\frac{(8-2x)dx}{\sqrt{8x-x^2-15}}+17\int_{3}^{5}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(x-4)^2}}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\left[(x-4)\sqrt{1-(x-4)^2}+\sin^{-1}\left(x-4\right)\right]_{3}^{5}-4\left[2\sqrt{1-(x-4)^2}\right]_{3}^{5}+17\left[\sin^{-1}(x-4)\right]_{3}^{5}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}(\pi)-8(0)+17(\pi)=\frac{33\pi}{2}$$